# Why is atime updating when equal to mtime and ctime?

Tags: filesystems, mount, timestamps, atime

I'm trying to understand how inode access time is handled with the default "relatime" mount option in Linux, but the behavior documented in [mount(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) doesn't quite match what I see.  It says:

> **relatime**
>
> Update inode access times relative to modify or change time. Access time is only updated if the previous access time was earlier than the current modify or change time. (Similar to noatime, but doesn't break mutt or other applications that need to know if a file has been read since the last time it was modified.)

I can set up a test file with the same atime/mtime/ctime:

```
$ touch sometestfile
$ stat sometestfile 
  File: sometestfile
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 259,2   Inode: 38318274    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   user)   Gid: ( 1000/   user)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0
Access: 2023-03-24 16:56:56.758033579 -0400
Modify: 2023-03-24 16:56:56.758033579 -0400
Change: 2023-03-24 16:56:56.758033579 -0400
 Birth: 2023-03-24 16:56:56.758033579 -0400
```

But then, a subsequent read increments atime, even though atime was *not* earlier than the current modify or change time:

```
$ cat sometestfile
$ stat sometestfile
  File: sometestfile
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 259,2   Inode: 38318274    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   user)   Gid: ( 1000/   user)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0
Access: 2023-03-24 16:57:02.336950126 -0400
Modify: 2023-03-24 16:56:56.758033579 -0400
Change: 2023-03-24 16:56:56.758033579 -0400
 Birth: 2023-03-24 16:56:56.758033579 -0400
```

If I'm going by the man page, shouldn't it stay the same?  Is this just a case of "<" in the man page versus "<=" in the kernel source or something?  (This is basically the inverse of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88840); it makes sense to me that subsequent reads don't change atime, but I'm confused as to why it changes with the first read.)  I realize this is painfully nitpicky but I'm trying to wrap my head around all the edge cases involving a file's access time and just ran into this one.  I see this on kernel 6.1.9 on Fedora 37 and 6.2.6 on Arch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, “earlier” should be “not later”.

The behaviour you see is correct. Touching the file is a write. `atime` is updated on the first subsequent read.

Looks like a bug in the manual.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this. It is the same in my local copy of the manual. My brain just skipped over it. It autocorrected it as I read.

Comment: You're right!  I'd already tried to find this in the kernel source and failed, but was finally able to track it down just now to [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5ad4fe9613cb8c202150f5cce5347fc8926c6c01/fs/inode.c#L1805).  Pretty sure those `timespec64_compare(...) >= 0` lines must be the "not later" part.  Even the comment on that function has it slightly wrong.  Well, now we know.

Comment: I submitted https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/pull/2135 and a kernel patch to fix this (I’ll add the lore link when it’s available).

Comment: The kernel patch is https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20230325082232.2017437-1-steve@sk2.org/

Comment: I was worried that the patch would change behaviour. However, it is only a change to comments. (Comments are always wrong, and sometimes end up in the documentation)

Comment: Right, I wouldn’t want to change the behaviour, since it’s correct — if we change `relatime` to check strict inequality, it would result in missing atime updates in at least the first scenario (creating a new file). Both patches have been merged, the man page fix will be in the next release of `util-linux` (2.39, I think) and the kernel comment fixes will be in 6.4.